# How to connect airflow with local spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

I try to execute local spark job through airflow task:

```
spark = (SparkSession
            .builder
            .master("spark://172.22.102.229:7077")
            .appName("Test")
            .getOrCreate())
```

But get a error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
```

When i replace `.master("spark://172.22.102.229:7077")` to `.master("local")` it is working

My spark deployed and i can get web ui at `http://172.22.102.229:4040/` address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access Spark WebUI go to the WebUI and you will see something like this:
[image]

Use the URL to create your SparkSession. For example:

```
spark = SparkSession
            .builder
            .master("spark://10.0.6.187:7077")
            .appName("Test")
            .getOrCreate()
```

Hope this can help you! Best Regards

Comment: yeah thank you, in my case i also need to add SPARK_MASTER_HOST and SPARK_LOCAL_HOST variable and start spark master (conf/start-master.sh)
For details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430106/worker-failed-to-connect-to-master-in-spark-apache